# PHPunit test failed with Yii framework

Tags: yii, phpunit

My local system is WAMP (win 8.1) with Yii 1.1.14.

I had installed PHPUnit by pear.(CMD: pear install phpunit/PHPUnit)

But the test failed.
Could someone give me some hint? Many thanks.

Following is the error message.

```
C:\wamp\www\trackstar\protected\tests>phpunit --version
PHPUnit 4.0.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.
C:\wamp\www\trackstar\protected\tests>phpunit unit/DbTest.php
PHP Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php): failed to o
pen stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\test\CWebTest
Case.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install some extension, in this case Selenium. I assume you run selenium tests and that is you you have to extend that.

In Linux you would have to install it with

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
```

Not sure quite what the command is in Windows.